# What does string().copy() do?

Tags: c++

Can anyone explain what this code does?

```
Con(const char* n){
    char_number = new char[sizeof(n) + 1];
    string(n).copy(char_number, sizeof(n) + 1);
}
```

I don't understand the `string(n)` part. What exactly does this do?

Comment: It’s a very misleading name. Copy copies the string into the char array

Comment: Have you taken a first step of checking what [`std::string::copy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/copy) does? It would help if you could [edit] with which parts specifically you're having trouble understanding

Comment: `sizeof(n)` is very likey an error. It is the size of a pointer, not the length of the pointed string.

Comment: string(n) what does it do?

Comment: `string(n)` constructs a temporary std::string initialized from the c-string in `n` then uses copy to copy that std::string back to a character array. `sizeof(n)` is not correct. This is the size of a pointer and not the size of the string it points to.

Comment: Stupid question: Isn't n just the size of the string?

Comment: No, `n` is a pointer to a char array or a c-string

Comment: @Christian No, it's a `const char*`.

Comment: Today, I learned something new again. Thanks.

Comment: `std::size(n)` instead of `sizeof(n)` will do what you intend

Comment: @Camwin No it will not. std::size work for classes which has a size member function and for c arrays, but not for pointers.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/string/):

#### std::string::string

> **copy constructor**
> `string (const string& str);`
> Constructs a copy of str.

> **from c-string**
> `string (const char* s);`
> Copies the null-terminated character sequence (C-string) pointed by s.

Note: `.copy()` [is explained here](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/copy/).